# integrals with no analytic answer - intuition and proof

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, intuition

It appears that the following integral has no analytic solution:

$$\int_0^\pi e^{\sin(x)} \, dx$$

Intuitively, what is the reason for this integral having no analytic answer? (is there a way to prove it formally?)

More generally, when and why do some integrals have no analytic answer and how can one gain intuition about what types of functions have no analytic integrals?

Comment: You obviously  confuse the terms "analytic" and "elementary".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially if you start with some initial set of functions and consider the functions formed by composing and multiplying them, then the product and chain rules say that differentiating doesn't broaden the class of functions you're considering, whereas there are no analogous rules for integration.

You can prove that the integral of a given elementary function is non-elementary using differential Galois theory.

Edit: see comments.

Comment: For antiderivatives, differential Galois theory (the Risch algorithm) does allow you to prove this.  But the OP asked about a **definite** integral.  That's quite a different matter.

Comment: You're right, of course; I wasn't paying enough attention. I don't even know what the relevant notion is for a number to have a "closed form" -- maybe a value of an elementary function at a rational value of x?

Comment: Certainly not that.  Constant functions are elementary, so every real number is a value of an elementary function at a rational $x$.

Comment: Fair enough, although there's no serious obstruction to defining the class of "elementary functions with rational constants."  Is there any agreed-upon notion of which constants are "elementary," short of computability?  (Obviously it would usually be nearly impossible to prove that a given number didn't belong to such a class, but we could still have an idea of what the appropriate class ought to be.)

Answer (score 4):

Actually, your example does have a "closed form", although not elementary:
$$ \pi ({\bf L}_0(1) + I_0(1))$$
where ${\bf L}_0$ is a modified Struve function and $I_0$ is a modified Bessel function.

Comment: didn't know that. it was a bad example. the question stands though: why/when do some definite integrals have no analytic answer? how to gain intuition about this using a simple example?

Comment: AFAIK very little is known in general about closed forms for definite integrals of elementary functions.

Comment: Of course there are various methods that sometimes produce such a closed form.  When none of the known methods apply, and numerical evaluation produces a number that isn't easily recognizable, we might strongly suspect that there is no closed form, but to prove such a statement (for any reasonable definition of "closed form") is essentially hopeless.

Comment: many texts assert, when motivating monte carlo simulations, that integrals of various products of probability distributions have "no analytic form". so is this a proven statement or speculation based on the fact that no one has been able to do the integral and the results from numerical are "unrecognizable" as you say?

Comment: Probably they mean that the indefinite integral is non-elementary, which can be proven in many cases.  As Robert mentioned, though, it's much, much harder to show that there's not a simple expression for the definite integral, which is just a number.